# Filter out actions in redux devtool extension

Tags: redux, redux-devtools-extension

I have an action which is dispatched every one second. Its dispatched from a web socket connection which receives data every one second.

This causes my devtool to be filled with a lot of these actions and therefore makes debugging hard for other actions and stuff.

[image]

Is there a way to filter out all this "noise" from the logger

I tried doing the following:

```
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    actionsBlacklist: 'METER_DATA_RECEIVE'
  }) || compose;
```

but this not only filters out the action from the logger but also from the application. i.e, it isn't dispatched so its as good as not calling the action which is what I don't want.

In other words, I want the actions dispatched but not logged in the redux dev tool

Answer (score 10):

You can configure this within the browser.

In the `Redux DevTools Extension` settings there is an option `Filter actions in DevTools`. Just enter "METER_DATA_RECEIVE" there.

To modify the extension settings either click the gear icon in the very bottom right corner of the Redux tab or select `Extension Options` in the Chrome Extension details screen.

Comment: Doesn't work. It causes redux to also ignore those actions which causes the store to not update at all.

Comment: The application still gets these messages and its store updates. But you are right, since the Redux extension does not show this action, you also do not see the new state there. However, any new (and shown) action in the Redux extension will give you the current state of store (including changes from filtered actions).

Comment: I had to right click the extension icon and then press `options`.

Comment: DONT DO THIS. I lost 2 days of work by doing this.

Answer (score 6):

I'm filtering out actions within my code using this method its working perfectly - actions are filtererd out but still dispatched.

If you are using other middlewear, perhaps this is messing with it.

```
middlewares.push(ReduxPromise, reduxThunk);
let composeEnhancers = compose;

const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    actionsBlacklist: [
         'METER_DATA_RECEIVE',
         'METER_UPLOAD_PARTS',
    ]
  }) || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));
```

Comment: It's now showing `actionsBlacklist` as deprecated. It suggests to use `actionsDenyList` instead. It works perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this add-on...

https://github.com/bvaughn/redux-devtools-filterable-log-monitor

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, using RTK, Redux Toolkit:

```
const store = configureStore({
reducer: rootReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware)=> getDefaultMiddleware(),
devTools: {actionsDenyList: [‘mySlice/myAction’]}
)};
```